# Dagger2 allow injection to be null

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

So, in short, I have a lot of flavors of the same app with slight differences. I would like to add a Navigator for all flavors independently. I'm using Dagger2, and I have a sub component for each flavor where I inject things only for a given flavor. So I would like to inject a Navigator class too.

The trick is, that some of the classes in the common code use this navigator too, with a null check. So if it's null, fine, but if not then do x.

So I'd like to have a field like:

```
@Inject @Nullable Navigator navigator;
```

Dagger gives me an error if there is no @Provides method for something like this, but that's exactly what I want, I want the @Provides to go in the submodules but still inject in the common code base.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No unfortunately, Dagger apparently does not support this

Answer (score 6):

To support a nullable type you just have to add a `@Nullable` annotation on your `@Provides` method that returns the nullable type and Dagger will accept it.

If you don't, Dagger will complain that you can only provide nullable types from `@Nullable` annotated methods.

Comment: You also need to include \@Nullable on the receiving side too [source](https://dagger.dev/api/2.12/dagger/Provides.html) "If a @Provides method is marked \@Nullable, Dagger will only allow injection into sites that are marked \@Nullable as well."

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to go down the road of having nullable objects injected, you can return an `Optional<Navigator>` in your dagger module - you'll end up with cleaner code in the long run.