# How to filed inject a nullable type in an activity with dagger 2 and kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a this dependency that I want to inject in some activity. I'm using `dagger.android` and did all the setup and the project compiles perfectly

In the AppModule:

```
 @Provides
 fun provideAppDrawable(application: Application): Drawable? {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(application, R.drawable.logo)
 }
```

In the activity:

```
@Inject lateinit var logo: Drawable
```

Now when I try to run the app, Dagger 2 throws this error `error: [Dagger/Nullable] android.graphics.drawable.Drawable is not nullable`

Is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163643/2754562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about **Null Safety** in kotlin. From [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html):

> In Kotlin, the type system distinguishes between references that can
>   hold null (nullable references) and those that can not (non-null
>   references). For example, a regular variable of type String can not hold null:
>
> ```
> var a: String = "abc"
> a = null // compilation error
> ```
>
> To allow nulls, we can declare a variable as nullable string, written String?:
>
> ```
> var b: String? = "abc"
> b = null // ok
> ```

So, you must either provide `Drawable` (without ?), or change your variable type in activity to `Drawable?` (with ?).

Comment: Yes but  `ContextCompat.getDrawable()`  returns a nullable type and if I change the variable type to nullable like this  `@Inject lateinit var logo: Drawable?`, it throws an error and that is the issue

Comment: Because `lateinit` modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types. So, you must remove it too.

Comment: I tried this `@Inject var logo: Drawable? = null` but then I got another error `error: Dagger does not support injection into private fields`

Comment: Try `@set:Inject` instead of `@Inject`.